# using volley to post username and password to php, parsing the returned json array into shared preferences

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to send the username and password to the server, with the server returning a json array of the users information. I am then trying to store the information passed into shared preferences. Here is my attempt. I tried to Toast out the information at the bottem of the code, but the String values are coming up as null.

```
    private void jsonParse() {
    String url = "http://178.128.166.68/getUserInfo.php";


    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("profileData");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject profileData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            id = profileData.getString("id");
                            fNameGet = profileData.getString("fName");
                            lNameGet = profileData.getString("lName");
                            phoneGet = profileData.getString("phone");
                            joinedDateGet = profileData.getString("joined");
                            noOfTripsGet = profileData.getString("noOfTrips");


                        }

                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("phone", phoneGet);
                        editor.putString("fName", fNameGet);
                        editor.putString("lName", lNameGet);
                        editor.putString("joined", joinedDateGet);
                        editor.putString("Trips", noOfTripsGet);

                        editor.commit();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_name", username);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    mQueue.add(request);
    Toast.makeText(this, id + fNameGet + lNameGet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

PHP code

```
$username = $_POST["user_name"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];


$qry = "select * from user where phone like '$username' and pass = '$pass';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

$rows=array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode(array('profileData' =>$rows));


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

As i am quite inexperienced with this any criticism or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _Silly question probably_ is the column `phone` really the same as `username`?

Comment: Should you be using `=` and not `like` in that query

Comment: You should use an application like postman to see what the data is returning from the server

Comment: Do you have a debugger in the java end, so you can look at what is being returned. Its probably the output from `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: no its not  a silly question, i was originally gonna use a username for logins but i changed it to phone number. just me being lazy and not changing it yet. sorry for the confusion

Comment: but you are passing `username` and trying to match it with `phone` ???

Comment: "it is returning null"  What specifically is returning `null`?  Pretty sure that your PHP couldn't possibly be sending `null` as a response.

Comment: Sorry the string values i am trying to set in the Toast are returning as null, so the data isnt being set.